# Unable to add custom fonts in platform iOS NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

I have followed the guidelines in the official documentation to add a custom font to my native script application. https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling#custom-fonts

The font name is Ubuntu as shown in the image below.
[image]

I added the font Ubuntu.ttf under the folder /fonts of my project, and add the following to my app.css file :

[image]

```
.Ubuntu
{
    font-family: Ubuntu;
}
```

However, once strating the application I cannot see the font applied to my label.

```
<Label class="Ubuntu" text="This is a test message" ></Label>
```

Any help will be much more appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, the wonderful fonts issue on iOS.   Fortunately this is something that is easy to fix.

I actually have an entire [blog article](http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=176) on how to fonts in NativeScript.

But to simple answer your specific question the font is not actually named "Ubuntu"; that is the file name.  If you look at the top-middle of your font picture you will see the name is actually "**Ubuntu Gras**".
[image: Ubuntu Gras]

So your CSS should actually look like this.

```
.Ubuntu
{
    font-family:Ubuntu,Ubuntu Gras;
}
```

What this does is cause iOS and Android to auto-load the "Ubuntu.ttf" file when they can't find a font already loaded called "Ubuntu" in the system loaded fonts.  (Note: The physical file name should **always** be the first definition.)

So after it loads it, it then tries to use "Ubuntu" as the font lookup; but this can fail on iOS on some fonts (but always works on Android).   So then because it can't find the "Ubuntu" name, it uses the next available font name which we so conveniently provided for it -- "Ubuntu Gras".  Since the font was already loaded (i.e. from the "Ubuntu" name) then the iOS operating system can now find the "Ubuntu Gras" name, and so it uses it properly.

Comment: Thats works like a charm. Thanks a lot for your time and explanations. Have a nice day.